# How do I stop my AsyncTask from downloading further?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using AsyncTask to download a file. It also shows a progress dialog and has a cancel button, when I click cancel it is supposed to stop the AsyncTask from downloading further but it is not doing anything.

cancel button code:

```
 new DownloadFileAsync().cancel(true);
```

Asynctask:

```
 class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        if (!isCancelled()) {
            File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            File FileDirectory = new File(dir, guessed_file_name);
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
                URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                conexion.connect();
                int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(FileDirectory);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", progress[0]);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "download completed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        finish();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you need to create an object and then use that object for execution as well as canceling the task.

So for starting AsyncTask as per your code, you must be doing

```
new DownloadFileAsync().execute(<your inputs>);
```

What you need to do it, declare a class level global variable and use that for start execution

```
DownloadFileAsync mDownloadFileAsync = null; //declare as class global 

mDownloadFileAsync = new DownloadFileAsync();

mDownloadFileAsync.execute(<your inputs>);
```

For canceling use this DownloadFileAsync instance

```
if (mDownloadFileAsync != null && mDownloadFileAsync.getStatus == AsyncTask.Status.Running){

    mDownloadFileAsync.cancel(true);

}
```

And also modify your while loop condition inside AsyncTask as mentioned by @Gabe Sechan and @Miraz Mahmud

```
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1 && !isCancelled())
```

Comment: it works but when i try downloading again it crashes " Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)"

Comment: You need to initialize task variable everytime you need to execute.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like this. You need reference to your asynctask.
1. first you need to create object

```
DownloadFileAsync downloadTask = new DownloadFileAsync();
```

2. execute it

```
dowloadTask.execute();
```

3. on this object reference u can call .cancel(true)

```
downloadTask.cancel(true);
```

Comment: where do i create the object ? in oncreate?

Comment: yeah sure! you can do it in oncreate();

Comment: You may have to create default constructor in your DownloadFileAsync class.

Answer (score 0):

You're only checking isCanceled once.  You need to do it every so often within the function as well, or it won't actually stop.  A good place is in your while loop, change it into `while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1 && !isCancelled())`

Comment: I did exactly what you said, but it didn't work. Its still downloading in background

Answer (score 0):

It's seems you check `isCancelled()` only once before the download started. add the checking on progress like below

```
while (((count = input.read(data)) != -1) && !isCancelled()) {

}
```

Comment: you also creating a new async task to cancelling!. Be sure to cancel the same task that you are created before. DownloadFileAsync downloadFileAsync = DownloadFileAsync(); downloadFileAsync.cancel(true);